# Space below an underline

Tags: pdftex

How can I add some space between the underlined line and the next line?
[image]

```
\item \underline{Long line of text underlined to demonstrate:} \\
This is too close to the above underline and it's a bit hard to read .
```

Comment: ``\\[1ex]`` should do. But don't use underlining.

Comment: Thank you, but why not? Is there a better way?

Comment: underlying is almost never used in printed works. It's a convention mostly used on typewriters that had limited possibility of font changes.

Comment: @Panayiotis: As far as a "better" way that is subjective, but I'd recommend using `\textbf` instead, or `\textsl{}`, or even `\textsl{\textbf{}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to provide the optional paramter to `\\`, or using `enumitem` control the spacing with `parsep=` option:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \ul{Long line of text underlined to demonstrate:} \\[2.0ex]
    This was too close to the above underline but now it is not.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[parsep=2.0ex]
    \item \ul{Long line of text underlined to demonstrate:}
    
    This was too close to the above underline but now it is not.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```